# PDF is not generating for huge HTML file (approx. 31MB) using pupeteer (version 19.6.0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I am facing a problem where HTML file is not converted into PDF. Size of HTML file is 31MB. My HTML file contains tables and rows (approx. 400k rows)

I am using Pupeteer (version 19.6.0) library

This is my code

```js
(async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      const html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname , 'test.html'), 'utf-8');
      await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
      const pdf = await page.pdf({
                  path: 'report.pdf',
                  margin: { top: '100px', right: '50px', bottom: '100px', left: '50px' },
                  printBackground: true,
                  format: 'A4',
                  displayHeaderFooter: true,
                  pageRanges: "",
                  timeout:0,
      });

      await browser.close();
})();
```

I am getting error at `await page.pdf()` line and the error is:

Error generating PDF:  ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed
at D:\ETMS\ETMSBACKEND\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:329:24
at new Promise ()
at CDPSessionImpl.send (D:\ETMS\ETMSBACKEND\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:325:16)
at CDPPage.createPDFStream (D:\ETMS\ETMSBACKEND\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:746:88)
at CDPPage.pdf (D:\ETMS\ETMSBACKEND\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:772:37)
at D:\ETMS\ETMSBACKEND\src\services\report\report-details\report-details.service.js:454:60
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Please avoid using local words like *lac*. It's not used or understood globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `page.goto("file://to-html", { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })`
instead of `page.setContent()`. [This](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11720#issuecomment-1906278485) resolved ProtocolError, I am receiving.

However, I still cannot generate the a PDF with ~19MB HTML file with either methods.